# Check if a file exists from a file name/path given in a text file?

Tags: c

I have a text file called test.txt that contains the following text:

> filepath /Desktop/file.txt

I need to get the path after the word filepath and check to see if that file actually exists in the filesystem.

I've used strchr() and strtok() to extract the "/Desktop/file.txt" from the text file and use that with the access() function to check for existence. However, it never actually works and says that it doesn't exist every single time even though it actually does exist.

Here is part of my code to try and get this to work.

```
char *buffer = 0;
long length;
FILE *getfile;
getfile = fopen("test.txt", "r");

if (getfile){
    fseek (getfile, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (getfile);
    fseek (getfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc (length);
    if (buffer){
        fread (buffer, 1, length, getfile);
        }
    fclose (getfile);
}

char *getfilepath = (strchr(buffer, 'filepath') + 2);

int filepathexists = access(getfilepath, F_OK);

if(filepathexists == 0){
    printf("The file exists.");
} else {
    printf("File does NOT exist.");
}
```

Comment: You cannot use such a long character literal in `strchr`. A proprer compiler (or enabling the proper compiling flags) should be warning for 'character literal too long'.

Comment: You've read the newline at the end of the file.  The file name does not include the newline.  Remove the newline and there's a decent chance the code will work if the root directory has a `/Desktop` sub-directory that you can access.  Are you sure that you have a `/Desktop` directory in `/`?  (Oh, and end your printing messages with a newline; it helps ensure the messages appear timely and don't get confused with the prompt for the next command, etc.)

Comment: Also note that the input from `fread()` is not going to be null terminated for you...so it reads an array of bytes and not a string.  You will need to capture the return value from `fread()` so you know how long the file name is.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the comment. I'm partially confused as to what newline I should be removing, the newline in the test.txt file? I already checked, the only line in that text file is the first line that says where the file is.

Comment: And the file likely ends with a newline, does it not?  If you use `cat` on the file, does your command prompt start on the same line as and after the file name, or is it on a line of its own?  If it's on its own line, then the file that your reading contains a newline that the file name you are trying to test almost certainly does not.  You can test all this out by printing what you read properly delimited: `printf("Line: <<%.*s>>\n", nbytes, buffer)` where `nbytes` is the number of bytes reported by `fread()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. The file input is read with `fgets()` and the keyword is tested with `strstr()`. I use `strtok()` to isolate the pathname from any trailing `newline` etc, but because a path can contain a space, I have been careful to check for leading spaces independently. NB don't forget to `free()` the memory you allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    int filepathexists = 0;
    char *buffer, *sptr;
    const char *cue = "filepath";
    size_t length;
    FILE *getfile;
    getfile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (getfile){
        fseek (getfile, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell (getfile);                  // find file size
        fseek (getfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = malloc (length + 1);              // allow for str terminator
        if (buffer){
            if (fgets(buffer, length + 1, getfile) != NULL) {
                sptr = strstr(buffer, cue);        // cue in correct place
                if (sptr == buffer) {
                    sptr += strlen(cue);           // skip past cue
                    while (*sptr == ' ')           // and leading spaces
                        sptr++;
                    sptr = strtok(sptr, "\r\n\t"); // isolate path from newlines etc
                    if (sptr) {
                        printf("The file is: %s\n", sptr);
                        if (access(sptr, 0) != -1) {
                            filepathexists = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            free (buffer);
        }
        fclose (getfile);
    }

    if (filepathexists)
        printf("The file exists.\n");
    else
        printf("File does NOT exist.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
The file is: /Desktop/file.txt
The file exists.
```